# Storing data in a Loader to access on the LoadCallback

Tags: actionscript-3

I constantly find myself in need of storing data on a Loader so that when the LoadCallback is fired I can perform certain logic based on the data.

I have been using the name field of the loader recently to store small amounts of data, like a string for the ID of the object I am loading, but that is very limited. Are there any ways to store data on a Loader outside of this?

I'm thinking that I can make my own loader class that extends Loader and have it store any data I care about, but I wanted to check if there are better methods before I go and do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no field allowing you to store custom data as the Loader or LoaderInfo class are defined.

You can totally extend your Loader, or use `function closure` to achieve that.

```
var myThing = new Thing();

var l = new Loader();
l.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function()
{
    trace(myThing);
    //Do things with myThing
});
```